# How to delay exec command in php

Tags: php, command, exec, delay, iptables

I know this kind of question has been asked many times, but I haven't found a suitable answer yet. Here it is:

I have a site - apache/php/mysql on debian.
I've managed to allow www-data to execute iptables commands. Now I need to find out if I can delay such a command without making the user/browser wait.

What's the point? - When a user authenticates php will get his public IP address and will open a port in the firewall. I want this port to be open for (let's say) 2 minutes (enough time to establish a VPN connection), and then I want the port to be closed.

So, basically, I want PHP to exec a command, and then, after 2 minutes, to execute another command - all this without making the browser wait for those two minutes.

From the user's perspective: John authenticates at test.com and immediately closes his browser and starts his vpn connection. If he closes the VPN connection after the 2 minute period, he has to logon again.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `at`:

```
shell_exec('echo "iptables --something 1.2.3.4" | at now + 2 minutes');
```

Comment: This won't work if you have the user "www-data" in /etc/at.deny (it was by default on my pc)

Answer (score 2):

have php execute a bash script that runs the iptables command for you after for sleeping for 2 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Run it as a seperate script and don't wait for it to finish,

```
exec("/usr/bin/php script.php &");
```

Comment: Not the ideal solution, but should work so long as `max_execution_time` is above 2 minutes.

Comment: True, I'd generally use a perl script instead of php depending on the task.